# Non jta datasource connection on JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: sql, jboss, connection, persistence

Hi i'm new baby for Jboss:D. 

This error few day my headache.

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4003]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception
>   Description: Configuration error.  Class
>   [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver] not found.

My JBoss standalone.xml driver tag:

```
<driver name="MSSQLXA" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class></driver>
```

My application persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="Entities" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation"
            value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.5:1433;databaseName=ADiamond;"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
            value="diamond"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.mode"
            value="Transactional"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.cache.storeMode" value="REFRESH"/>
</properties>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of JBoss? Are you intentionally combining a xa-datasource with a RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction-type?

Comment: Hi thank you answering post. i'm using jboss-as-7.1.0.Final. yes combining a xa-datasource with resource_local

Comment: Did you create a module named "com.microsoft.sqlserver" for the driver? See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7 on how to do this. If you just copied the driver to the deployments folder the module name needs to be the same as the name of the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an error saying that JDBC driver class was not found. Download [SQL Server JDBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2505)  and copy in to `<JBOSS_HOME>\common\lib` folder and check your program.

Comment: HI i using version jboss-as-7.1.0.Final. where is common folder?